# Google chrome sync API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, synchronization

Is there an API that allows accessing Google Chrome sync data, such as bookmarks, history and opened tabs, by a third-party web application, ideally using only client-side javascript?

#### Purpose

I am trying to write a self-contained HTML app, that can synchronize reading progress of webcomics across mobile and desktop devices. Ideally, such functionality would be redundant, as bookmarks in theory can fill that purpose. In practice however, especially mobile versions of Chrome lack the means to conveniently update bookmarks, and sorting mechanisms (e.g. sorting by last-modified date). Note that these issues only become apparent when following upwards of 50 webcomics, most of which at that point will only be caught up on very rarely.

Since this is meant as a hobby project, the cost of hosting a webservice or developing for iOS are prohibitive, thus the attempt to reuse existing cloud accounts of the user for synchronization.

#### Possible discontinued API

Until roughly one or two years ago, the Dolphin and Mercury browsers on iOS allowed synchronizing with Google Chrome directly, by authenticating the app for access to one's Google account. At that time both browsers required that bookmarks were synchronized without an encryption passphrase.

Then suddenly they both dropped this feature, and instead started providing their own synchronization extensions and servers (again, without end-to-end encryption).

So I fear, that Google might have once provided a limited public synchronization API, which was dropped within the last two years; I was however unable to verify even this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they dropped support

> We locked down access to chromesync scoped refresh tokens to address a security vulnerability. When we did so, we knew that this may break some 3P browsers which made use of chromesync scoped refresh tokens to leverage Chrome Sync for their users.
>
> Chrome Sync has never officially been supported for 3P browsers. We do not intend to create a solution by which 3P browsers can whitelist themselves or their users so that they can get chromesync scoped refresh tokens. Note that Chromium for Android is technically considered a 3P browser.
>
> Marking as WontFix, accordingly.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677887